# Reordering of data segments within a file

Tags: c#, java, c++, language-agnostic

I am trying to find an algorithm in with perhaps an example in C, C++, C#, Java or really any language to help solve a reordering problem I have been facing.

The objective is to take a series of ranges in a file, and reorganize in a new pattern, basically shifting pieces of data around without destroying the integrity of the data. I would preferrably like to find one that can perform it in-place and use a single buffer for swapping, or direct movement from one place to another. The reorganizing process can break down the ranges into pieces as long as the ranges have the same length and data integrity when complete.

As an example, given a set of values:

```
  Length    SrcStart     Src End   Dst Start     Dst End
    9178      274054      283231           0        9177
  274051           0      274050        9178      283228
  582929      283229      866157      283229      866157
  399208      874397     1273604      866158     1265365
    8239    14675709    14683947     1265366     1273604
  986980     1273605     2260584     1273605     2260584
  602862     2811144     3414005     2260585     2863446
  138712     4092072     4230783     2863447     3002158
  116210     3414007     3530216     3002159     3118368
  550559     2260585     2811143     3118369     3668927
  561856     3530217     4092072     3668928     4230783
24319165     4230784    28549948     4230784    28549948
  578539    30246149    30824687    28549949    29128487
  491856    28549949    29041804    29128488    29620343
  593580    29639113    30232692    29620344    30213923
  597308    29041805    29639112    30213924    30811231
   13456    30232693    30246148    30811232    30824687
  633513    31407949    32041461    30824688    31458200
  583261    30824688    31407948    31458201    32041461
40117358    32041462    72158819    32041462    72158819
```

All of the contents in the SrcStart -> SrcEnd ranges need to be moved to the DstStart -> DstEnd range. Take note that in many cases, a shift from the Source to the Destination will cause the contents of the Destination to be altered, of which you cannot copy from that location any longer since the original data that was needed has been destroyed.

The objective is to move each segment of data from the SrcStart to the DstStart with the Length in the first column. Each line's corresponding "End" is simply the start plus the length minus one (so its the actual offset).

I've done quite a bit of research, and looked at swapping values, and breaking down areas that cross with other values as well as container within a container swapping, but they seem to fall short. So, as a result, this brings me back to my first statement of which I was hoping perhaps there was an algorithm or some source that I could learn from to help solve this problem, and the shared knowledge of the community just seemed to the way to go.

Thanks!

Comment: have you considered Reading the values into a Dictionary<int,int> or a HashTable or a List<> or SortedList if you are reading this from a file, you should be able to quickly load the data from the file into a collection or multiple list or multiple HashTables and use the Add, remove, sort methods on that List. I am assuming that the data is layed out just like that in a file..? if worse comes to wors you could always create an enum with the field names and use the (int) value of the enum which would represent the fieldnames declared in the enum as a header layout.

Comment: How was this list of move actions actually calculated? Are you defragmenting? Then check this link: http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/defragmentation-algorithm-757280.html

Comment: I think you can skip the last row, because source and destination are the same: `40117358    32041462    72158819    32041462    72158819` Oh, and also the 3rd, 6th and 12th line.

Comment: @DJKRAZE John is trying to rearrange data that is at locations specified by the rows in the table, he is not trying to rearrange the table contents. Maybe he should make that a bit more clear.

Comment: I agree.. thanks for the clarification it's hard for one to gather that from his initial post. thanks again have a good weekend everyone

Comment: @JohnDoesDone there is something odd in your data (besides the duplicate rows). One location, `4092072`, is moved to two other locations. This is probably not correct if you intended to rearrange data, and it causes typical memory efficient algorithms to fail.

Comment: @DJ Kraze - I have, and actually I'm using an interval tree to do my range lookups. I also maintain a sorted list for source and dest values. Its really the issue of 'when' you actually go to swap the data because you have to do it in a particular order, or else it will destroy contents that may need to be moved in the future. In theory, it sounds so simple, until you reduce it to practice and the gotchas come out.

Comment: @TheNail - It is similar to a defrag, but more of a rearranging of objects by usage inside of its own file set. Thank you for the link, I will go check it out. And yes, the last line is a straight copy to copy (as well as the 283229-866157 line. As for the duplicate, you'll find that it happens with the first line as well. The data is actually a copy of the same contents for that overlap (283231 overlaps 283229 by 2 bytes yet 283229 is moved later on).

Comment: @DJKraze - My apologies on not making it clear about the rows. That is a correct observation. I need each data segment moved from source to dest. I updated the original post to reflect, and thank you for the responses, they are appreciated.

Comment: @JohnDoesDone the point about copying data from one source location to multiple destination is still not clear to me. If you really want to make two or more copies, then this should be done in a separate operation; not when rearranging. If you want to apply an in-place algorithm to rearrange data, then you need to be able to use a source location to store other data after having copied the data to the destination.

Comment: @JohnDoesDone I have an algorithm that works if each original source has at most one destination. If you are interested, then I can post it.

Comment: Please do, I would be very interested in seeing it. I can carve out the overlaps in a separate operation. Thanks

Comment: @TheNail Forgot to post @ you with interest in the algorithm you mentioned, and cant reedit the last post.

Comment: @JohnDoesDone The algorithm is based on the principle that you can use the src-locations to store the data that was first at dst, and relocating the remaining ranges in the table, but Im afraid the algorithm still has some flaws which may or may not be fixable. I will try to fix it, but maybe you should also consider reserving extra memory, as Peter Lawrey suggests.

Comment: @TheNail I can live with flaws, it was more of the theory and example code of algorithm. As long as the algorithm is sound, I can work through the example code you have. Thanks again.

Comment: @JohnDoesdone I'm sorry, but I give up. The problem is that all the administration keeping track of what is moved where takes up too much space.

Comment: @JohnDoesdone If you are managing objects in limited memory then this article on Java garbage collection may be interesting to read: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-1996/jw-08-gc.html

Comment: @TheNail - No problem, I sincerely appreciate your effort to help. I'll take a look at the link, and when I come up with a solution, I'll post it here, just in case it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: If any answer was correct or helpful please accept or upvote.

Comment: I had not seen updates in awhile, and just found your comment below. I posted a response, and thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the approach that disk defragmaters use.

- Copy the data you need to overwrite to a free area first
- Change any indexes referring to that data to point to the new location, so the copy is used in future.
- You may have to keep note if any blocks become "unused", if the system has a concept of that.

However if the indexes are in bytes, it means the whole file is only 80 MB. A file that small can be copies very quickly (take less than two seconds) Perhaps the real example is much longer.  How large is the file in total?

Comment: The file is indeed 80 megs, but there are others that can be as large as 2GB in side, which of course you would never want to load into memory in a non-server environment. That said, the issue with this file is that there really isn't any free space to be used. Its all pure shifts and using another file as a 'dumping ground' would only double the necessary space to perform the task, thus defeating the idea of in-place.

Comment: You need to have some space to work to copy the data around, even if that is a portion in memory.  My PC has 24 GB and its not exactly a server. ;)

Comment: This is targeted for the average consumer PC has 2GB-4GB of memory. I don't mind using say 8-16 megs of memory to swap things around and have it accounted for, as I could do multiple read/write patterns in 16 meg bursts should be pretty fast as well.

Comment: The problem with doing this in place, and in memory is that if the process is interrupted at any point, the file will be corrupted. However you can re-write portions.  It won't be any faster than making a copying the file and deleting the original when finished, but its is riskier.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is a self correcting audit system that can fix corrupted objects, so i'm not worried about that. I understand all of the outskirting things that might happen, but please understand that the objective here is still about moving the data, or finding an algorithm or code that may assist to help that along.

Comment: If you don't have worry about memory or copying the data on disk, the solution is trivial. Its the implied constraints which make this harder, which is why they need to be clear.

Comment: Peter, my concern is when I have files that are 2GB+ on a consumer PC machine. This would cause an average machine to start paging like crazy, and cause the process to become incredibly slow, or even worse, crash due to inability to service a memory allocation. If the solution was just copy to memory, I could easily service it all by copying it all in, and writing segments back out. Or if I were to do it to another file, same idea. But consider 10 shifts of 20 megs forward/back in a 2GB file. I would copy 2GB of data for 400 megs if I went to another file, and 2GB of mem to move a 20 meg block

Comment: Even an optimal solution will involve significant amounts of paging. At a minimum it has to read 2 GB and write 2 GB (except perhaps data which does not move).  Writing the data in place will involve more reads/writes as it has to keep data which is in the same block but not moved in that operation.

Comment: If you were to use a second file, I wouldn't copy it all back again, instead to would replace the first file with the second file which is very fast.

Comment: Copying it back would be pointless. As for paging, I also get to do the fun of writing FSDs, so I'm familiar with all the joyous Cc and Mm calls at that level. However when changing out 30 megs of data in a 2GB file, it makes no sense to copy 1.97 Gb of data to do the changeout. The reality is that the small gap of data would be managed by the cache blocks kept in memory and done by exchange pointers and then flushed out by the Lazy writer, which is relatively efficient at its job. Versus blasting pages with data that you do not need to touch. Thanks for trying to help, I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the question as if it was an opaque binary file, in which for some reason you want to swap blocks about. It seems very unlikely that that is really the case. Surely the file has some structure of its own?  Can't you make use of that to help your bookkeeping?

- Does the file have a concept of "Used" and "unused" areas?
- Does the file have an internal structure of block headers?
- Does the file have any associated index or whatever which needs to be kept in sync? (If not, from where did you get the list of blocks to move?)
- Can blocks to move overlap each other? Note that if they can the order of operations becomes significant.

That said, the approach reccomended by @Peter Lawrey is good. If overwriting a block, first copy it to another location in the file, update any overlapping indexes.

In all it looks to me like you have tried to solve a hard problem by breaking it down into two steps, one easy, the other... even harder. What was the original problem?

(Obligatory suggestion: On Windows the transactional IO APIs may be of use).

Comment: There is no "standard" format, it can be any binary format. An example is lets say you have a zip file, and unzip it, then resort all the names, and zip it back up. You would have very little changed data (indices), but the majority of the data would be unchanged, just moved around in the file, which does not give you really any large "holes" to work with until you start lifting objects. You could solve the depleting hole space by taking all 'shift found' objects and sorting them by size so you lift larger objects out and supplant smaller objects in order, but doesn't solve the overall issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following algorithm can handle it with at most twice the largest chuck size memory for caching the data. You will need a book keeping FIFO, and your original list in addition to the data cache. It goes something like:

1. If both FIFO and movement table is empty, finish.
2. If FIFO is empty, move top entry from your movement table to FIFO, also read out the entry data into data cache.
3. Check if there are any blocks overlapping the destination area of the first entry in FIFO in the movement table.
4. If there is a block, read the data of the block into cache, move the entry to FIFO, go to 3.
5. If there are no blocks, write the data of the FIFO entry from cache to destination, remove the first FIFO entry, go to 1.

The idea is to find occupied blocks, cache them to open up space, and get rid of data in cache as quickly as possible. You may need to add some sanity checks to see if the source and destination addresses are identical. You may also want to do additional checks to see if the original table makes sense (two blocks moving to the same location, etc).

---

EDIT: I may have been to optimistic in stating maximum of largest block times two estimate. I think it can go beyond that. I think times 3 is a simple (but lax) upper bound.

Since you have quite large blocks in your source table, you can split them up to reduce cache usage. Say, you want to use at most 1 GB cache: split all blocks larger than 1/3GB to multiple entries of 1/3GB lengths before running the algorithm. Alternatively, you can make the algorithm work in sub-chunk sizes (instead of reading full chunks into cache, you read only the relevant parts, and keep modified entries in your source table), but I think that would be more difficult to manage/implement.

Comment: I'll think about this some, the issue I can see is that you must complete the chain flow once you begin (fwd or back), & every time you cross a boundary of 2 or more elements (think of section: 30246149-30824687 28549949-29128487 which crosses over 28549949-29041804 29128488-29620343 AND 29041805-29639112 30213924- 30811231, but you have to section out the parts that are a simple shift, & pre/post movement objects, then check to see what other object boundaries (since you now have 2 moving element objects by split, of which you need to do that split on the latter movement object) so it grows.

Comment: So 30246149-30824687 moving to 28549949-29128487 means i need the latter to go into the fifo first because we're about to overwrite it. However I'm going to need that data split and ready for not only 28549949-29041804 (going to 29128488-29620343), but for 29041805-29128487 / 29128488-29639112 by split & 30213924-30300606 / 30300607-30811231. If I run into anevent where it keeps splitting, I'll eventually overrun my buffer size as i'm compensating for multiple sections versus 1:1 section to point or even 1:2. Perhaps could show me a "Solve step by step" to the last 8 lines with your method?

Comment: First off, without splitting blocks, the algorithm above has a much higher bound than what I've predicted. Consider equal sized blocks packed together (identified by 1, 2, 3, 4, ....), and destinations for these blocks as 1->(2,3), 2->(4,5), 3->(6,7), 4->(8,9)...; where (i,j) means straddling i and j (since all blocks are same size, you can say offset is half the size into block i). The above setup will cause the FIFO to keep growing: 2,3; 3, 4, 5; 4, 5, 6, 7; 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 ... So, such a setup will grow the FIFO by one block for each block you try to move (you pop one, but push two more).

Comment: At this point, the best way to handle this would be to modify the algorithm to only move out the overlapping parts of the destination to the FIFO. That way, the size of the FIFO will always be bound by twice the size of the block pushed when it was empty (I think). The top of the FIFO can bring in only data less than or equal to its own size before it evacuates the spot, so the total size of the FIFO gradually falls off until it empties out. But this variant of the algorithm has higher complexity.

Comment: Your second point is also valid. If a portion of a shifting block is in FIFO, you end up splitting the shifting block until the whole shift is done. If you are throwing away the blocks inside FIFO once they are moved, this only causes inefficiency (split part to FIFO, FIFO to empty space, repeat until the whole block is shifted), with the degenerate case of splits of 1 byte. If you are keeping the housekeeping data around, you are in trouble. You will also need coalescing of split parts when done. You may want to detect shifting and handle it as a special case.